# hard to start to start the car when weather is cold

Tags: starting, mercedes-benz, c240

I have a 2001, C240 Mercedes Benz.  Recently i have noticed, when the weather is cold, it is hard to start. I checked the starter of the car and it is working. When i place the electrical key in the ignition, it makes no click or sound. After serval try (7-15) TIME, then it starts. the you help please